# WireGuard portforwarding setup

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, ssh-tunnel, wireguard

I need help with the following scenario:

I have a small instance on AWS, which should accept all traffic from ports 1024:65535 and should send it to my local server. The local server shouldn't send any traffic through the tunnel, just receive the traffic from the cloud server. To test this, the local server has a simple http server open on port 8080.

But I can't get it to work properly. I know the ports are open because when using a ssh tunnel this works perfectly.

Here is the server config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.1/24
PrivateKey = <private-server-key>
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens5 -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.200.2
PostUp = /usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]
PublicKey = <public-client-key>
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32
```

Here is the client config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.2/32
PrivateKey = <private-client-key>


[Peer]
PublicKey = <public-server-key>
Endpoint = <server-ip>:51820
```

I don't even get a handshake from the client on the server, except when I add

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

to the client config, but then nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

Policy routing for the client's reply traffic is probably the best approach. Try this for your WireGuard client config (assuming you are forwarding IPv4 traffic only):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.2/24
PrivateKey = <private-client-key>
Table = 123

PreUp = ip rule add from 10.200.200.2 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del from 10.200.200.2 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public-server-key>
Endpoint = <server-ip>:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

It uses a custom routing table (`123`) and a policy routing rule that ensures all replies to inbound traffic which originally came in the WireGuard interface will go out the same way -- without affecting traffic that originates on the client itself (except for traffic to the `10.200.200.0/24` range).

See the [WireGuard Port Forwarding From the Internet](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/09/wireguard-port-forward-from-internet/) article for a few other alternative options.

---

On the server side, if the client never initiates outbound connections (only replies to them), you can remove the server's `MASQUERADE` iptables rule (unless you're using it for some other reason).

And also, usually you wouldn't want to forward *everything* in the server's ephemeral port range, since usually you'd want to allow the server to use those ports for its own outbound connections (like to download system updates, for example). You'd be better off specifying just the ports your client is actually going to listen on in the server's `DNAT` iptables rule (or at least adjust it or the server's `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` kernel parameter to avoid mass collisions between the two).